# Batch script to download pdfs from chrome

Tags: windows, batch-file, pdf, download, save

Hi – I have multiple windows of pdf files open in chrome and I am flipping through manually (alt tab) and clicking download and save for each one. I am wondering if it is possible to simplify this with a batch file?

I am fairly new to this so any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: A batch file won't help there, but you could download `wget`, paste all your pdf files and create a batch file manually with all the wget commands to download them all sequentially.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I downloaded wget. Do I paste all the pdf urls into wget? Also, I have no experience with batch files. What code would allow me to download them all sequentially?

Comment: If you have no programming experience, you might want to look into Sikuli. It's an automation program which you can use mostly with screenshots and simple commands

Comment: You Can Download File Via `Wget` Commnad Also You Can Do This : `"%path-Chrome-Here%.exe https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19930073077.pdf"`